# Calculating quantiles of timeseries data and then create a "fanplot"

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

My code is working properly, but I am looking for better approach in the calculation of quantiles and the finding of the data in the dataframe.

```
import datetime
import pandas
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


colnames = ['Date', 'Energy']
df_1 = pd.read_csv('WTPV_Spring_2016.csv', names = colnames  , encoding="utf8", delimiter=";")

start_date = datetime(2022, 9, 27, 1, 0)
end_date = datetime(2022, 9, 28, 1, 0)

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    delta = timedelta(hours = 1)
    while start_date < end_date:
        yield start_date
        start_date += delta
        
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = 
['Time','pct0.1','pct0.2','pct0.3','pct0.4','pct0.5','pct0.6','pct0.7','pct0.8','pct0.9'])

for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
            df.loc[single_date, ['Time']] = single_date.strftime("%H:%M:%S")


x = []

for index in df.index:
    y = df_1.loc[df_1['Date'].str.contains(df['Time'][index])]
    for i in np.arange(1, 10, 1)/10:
        x.append(y.quantile(i))

pct = pd.DataFrame(x, columns = ['Energy'])

df['pct0.1'] = pct.loc[0.1].values
df['pct0.2'] = pct.loc[0.2].values
df['pct0.3'] = pct.loc[0.3].values
df['pct0.4'] = pct.loc[0.4].values
df['pct0.5'] = pct.loc[0.5].values
df['pct0.6'] = pct.loc[0.6].values
df['pct0.7'] = pct.loc[0.7].values
df['pct0.8'] = pct.loc[0.8].values
df['pct0.9'] = pct.loc[0.9].values

sns.set(font_scale = 1.5, style = "white")


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8, 6))

xs = np.arange(len(df))
colors = plt.cm.Greens(np.linspace(0.1, 0.6, 5))

for lower, upper, color in zip([f'pct0.{i}' for i in range(1, 5)], [f'pct0.{i}' for i in range(9, 5, -1)], colors):
    ax.fill_between(xs, df[lower], df[upper], color = color, label = lower + '-' + upper)

ax.plot(xs, df['pct0.5'], color = 'black' , lw = 1.5, label ='Median')
ax.set_xticks(xs)
ax.set_xticklabels(df['Time'], fontsize = 11)

ax.margins(x = 0)
ax.set_ylim(ymin = 0)

for sp in ['top', 'right']:
    ax.spines[sp].set_visible(True)

plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 11)
plt.title('WT & PV Spring 2016',  fontsize = 15)
plt.ylabel('Energy MWh',  fontsize = 12)
plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize = 12)

plt.ylim([0, 3200])

plt.show()
```

My data have a format like this:

```
2016/09/01 00:00:00;0
2016/09/01 01:00:00;0
2016/09/01 02:00:00;0
2016/09/01 03:00:00;0
2016/09/01 04:00:00;0
2016/09/01 05:00:00;0
2016/09/01 06:00:00;0
2016/09/01 07:00:00;0
2016/09/01 08:00:00;103
2016/09/01 09:00:00;420
2016/09/01 10:00:00;837
2016/09/01 11:00:00;1213
2016/09/01 12:00:00;1470
2016/09/01 13:00:00;1594
2016/09/01 14:00:00;1609
2016/09/01 15:00:00;1506
2016/09/01 16:00:00;1288
2016/09/01 17:00:00;994
2016/09/01 18:00:00;645
2016/09/01 19:00:00;309
2016/09/01 20:00:00;72
2016/09/01 21:00:00;0
2016/09/01 22:00:00;0
2016/09/01 23:00:00;0
2016/09/02 00:00:00;0
2016/09/02 01:00:00;0
2016/09/02 02:00:00;0
2016/09/02 03:00:00;0
2016/09/02 04:00:00;0
2016/09/02 05:00:00;0
2016/09/02 06:00:00;0
2016/09/02 07:00:00;0
2016/09/02 08:00:00;94
2016/09/02 09:00:00;376
2016/09/02 10:00:00;745
2016/09/02 11:00:00;1085
2016/09/02 12:00:00;1341
2016/09/02 13:00:00;1496
2016/09/02 14:00:00;1527
2016/09/02 15:00:00;1457
2016/09/02 16:00:00;1286
2016/09/02 17:00:00;1005
2016/09/02 18:00:00;659
2016/09/02 19:00:00;326
2016/09/02 20:00:00;76
2016/09/02 21:00:00;0
2016/09/02 22:00:00;0
2016/09/02 23:00:00;0
2016/09/03 00:00:00;0
2016/09/03 01:00:00;0
2016/09/03 02:00:00;0
2016/09/03 03:00:00;0
2016/09/03 04:00:00;0
2016/09/03 05:00:00;0
2016/09/03 06:00:00;0
2016/09/03 07:00:00;0
2016/09/03 08:00:00;100
2016/09/03 09:00:00;418
2016/09/03 10:00:00;840
2016/09/03 11:00:00;1220
2016/09/03 12:00:00;1483
2016/09/03 13:00:00;1622
2016/09/03 14:00:00;1648
2016/09/03 15:00:00;1568
2016/09/03 16:00:00;1374
2016/09/03 17:00:00;1086
2016/09/03 18:00:00;726
2016/09/03 19:00:00;355
2016/09/03 20:00:00;78
2016/09/03 21:00:00;0
2016/09/03 22:00:00;0
2016/09/03 23:00:00;0
2016/09/04 00:00:00;0
2016/09/04 01:00:00;0
2016/09/04 02:00:00;0
2016/09/04 03:00:00;0
2016/09/04 04:00:00;0
2016/09/04 05:00:00;0
2016/09/04 06:00:00;0
2016/09/04 07:00:00;0
2016/09/04 08:00:00;100
2016/09/04 09:00:00;430
2016/09/04 10:00:00;861
2016/09/04 11:00:00;1253
2016/09/04 12:00:00;1526
2016/09/04 13:00:00;1664
2016/09/04 14:00:00;1688
2016/09/04 15:00:00;1610
2016/09/04 16:00:00;1425
2016/09/04 17:00:00;1138
2016/09/04 18:00:00;762
2016/09/04 19:00:00;371
2016/09/04 20:00:00;79
2016/09/04 21:00:00;0
2016/09/04 22:00:00;0
2016/09/04 23:00:00;0
2016/09/05 00:00:00;0
2016/09/05 01:00:00;0
2016/09/05 02:00:00;0
2016/09/05 03:00:00;0
2016/09/05 04:00:00;0
2016/09/05 05:00:00;0
2016/09/05 06:00:00;0
2016/09/05 07:00:00;0
2016/09/05 08:00:00;98
2016/09/05 09:00:00;430
2016/09/05 10:00:00;865
2016/09/05 11:00:00;1263
2016/09/05 12:00:00;1539
2016/09/05 13:00:00;1673
2016/09/05 14:00:00;1697
2016/09/05 15:00:00;1603
2016/09/05 16:00:00;1384
2016/09/05 17:00:00;1078
2016/09/05 18:00:00;696
2016/09/05 19:00:00;320
2016/09/05 20:00:00;63
2016/09/05 21:00:00;0
2016/09/05 22:00:00;0
2016/09/05 23:00:00;0
2016/09/06 00:00:00;0
2016/09/06 01:00:00;0
2016/09/06 02:00:00;0
2016/09/06 03:00:00;0
2016/09/06 04:00:00;0
2016/09/06 05:00:00;0
2016/09/06 06:00:00;0
2016/09/06 07:00:00;0
2016/09/06 08:00:00;64
2016/09/06 09:00:00;252
2016/09/06 10:00:00;491
2016/09/06 11:00:00;718
2016/09/06 12:00:00;855
2016/09/06 13:00:00;920
2016/09/06 14:00:00;937
2016/09/06 15:00:00;831
2016/09/06 16:00:00;650
2016/09/06 17:00:00;478
2016/09/06 18:00:00;288
2016/09/06 19:00:00;128
2016/09/06 20:00:00;26
2016/09/06 21:00:00;0
2016/09/06 22:00:00;0
2016/09/06 23:00:00;0
2016/09/07 00:00:00;0
2016/09/07 01:00:00;0
2016/09/07 02:00:00;0
2016/09/07 03:00:00;0
2016/09/07 04:00:00;0
2016/09/07 05:00:00;0
2016/09/07 06:00:00;0
2016/09/07 07:00:00;0
2016/09/07 08:00:00;43
2016/09/07 09:00:00;172
2016/09/07 10:00:00;353
2016/09/07 11:00:00;537
2016/09/07 12:00:00;708
2016/09/07 13:00:00;913
2016/09/07 14:00:00;1011
2016/09/07 15:00:00;1002
2016/09/07 16:00:00;969
2016/09/07 17:00:00;797
2016/09/07 18:00:00;508
2016/09/07 19:00:00;238
2016/09/07 20:00:00;47
2016/09/07 21:00:00;0
2016/09/07 22:00:00;0
2016/09/07 23:00:00;0
2016/09/08 00:00:00;0
2016/09/08 01:00:00;0
2016/09/08 02:00:00;0
2016/09/08 03:00:00;0
2016/09/08 04:00:00;0
2016/09/08 05:00:00;0
2016/09/08 06:00:00;0
2016/09/08 07:00:00;0
2016/09/08 08:00:00;60
2016/09/08 09:00:00;247
2016/09/08 10:00:00;477
2016/09/08 11:00:00;692
2016/09/08 12:00:00;870
2016/09/08 13:00:00;1040
2016/09/08 14:00:00;1105
2016/09/08 15:00:00;1033
2016/09/08 16:00:00;905
2016/09/08 17:00:00;701
2016/09/08 18:00:00;444
2016/09/08 19:00:00;215
2016/09/08 20:00:00;42
2016/09/08 21:00:00;0
2016/09/08 22:00:00;0
2016/09/08 23:00:00;0
2016/09/09 00:00:00;0
2016/09/09 01:00:00;0
2016/09/09 02:00:00;0
2016/09/09 03:00:00;0
2016/09/09 04:00:00;0
2016/09/09 05:00:00;0
2016/09/09 06:00:00;0
2016/09/09 07:00:00;0
2016/09/09 08:00:00;60
2016/09/09 09:00:00;276
2016/09/09 10:00:00;555
2016/09/09 11:00:00;809
2016/09/09 12:00:00;995
2016/09/09 13:00:00;1124
2016/09/09 14:00:00;1160
2016/09/09 15:00:00;1103
2016/09/09 16:00:00;979
2016/09/09 17:00:00;769
2016/09/09 18:00:00;487
2016/09/09 19:00:00;220
2016/09/09 20:00:00;39
2016/09/09 21:00:00;0
2016/09/09 22:00:00;0
2016/09/09 23:00:00;0
2016/09/10 00:00:00;0
2016/09/10 01:00:00;0
2016/09/10 02:00:00;0
2016/09/10 03:00:00;0
2016/09/10 04:00:00;0
2016/09/10 05:00:00;0
2016/09/10 06:00:00;0
2016/09/10 07:00:00;0
2016/09/10 08:00:00;65
2016/09/10 09:00:00;310
2016/09/10 10:00:00;629
2016/09/10 11:00:00;925
2016/09/10 12:00:00;1152
2016/09/10 13:00:00;1310
2016/09/10 14:00:00;1349
2016/09/10 15:00:00;1265
2016/09/10 16:00:00;1096
2016/09/10 17:00:00;845
2016/09/10 18:00:00;531
2016/09/10 19:00:00;240
2016/09/10 20:00:00;41
2016/09/10 21:00:00;0
2016/09/10 22:00:00;0
2016/09/10 23:00:00;0
2016/09/11 00:00:00;0
2016/09/11 01:00:00;0
2016/09/11 02:00:00;0
2016/09/11 03:00:00;0
2016/09/11 04:00:00;0
2016/09/11 05:00:00;0
2016/09/11 06:00:00;0
2016/09/11 07:00:00;0
2016/09/11 08:00:00;73
2016/09/11 09:00:00;359
2016/09/11 10:00:00;726
2016/09/11 11:00:00;1066
2016/09/11 12:00:00;1305
2016/09/11 13:00:00;1443
2016/09/11 14:00:00;1472
2016/09/11 15:00:00;1386
2016/09/11 16:00:00;1197
2016/09/11 17:00:00;914
2016/09/11 18:00:00;569
2016/09/11 19:00:00;254
2016/09/11 20:00:00;41
2016/09/11 21:00:00;0
2016/09/11 22:00:00;0
2016/09/11 23:00:00;0
2016/09/12 00:00:00;0
2016/09/12 01:00:00;0
2016/09/12 02:00:00;0
2016/09/12 03:00:00;0
2016/09/12 04:00:00;0
2016/09/12 05:00:00;0
2016/09/12 06:00:00;0
2016/09/12 07:00:00;0
2016/09/12 08:00:00;66
2016/09/12 09:00:00;337
2016/09/12 10:00:00;695
2016/09/12 11:00:00;1041
2016/09/12 12:00:00;1310
2016/09/12 13:00:00;1478
2016/09/12 14:00:00;1510
2016/09/12 15:00:00;1426
2016/09/12 16:00:00;1241
2016/09/12 17:00:00;952
2016/09/12 18:00:00;595
2016/09/12 19:00:00;265
2016/09/12 20:00:00;42
2016/09/12 21:00:00;0
2016/09/12 22:00:00;0
2016/09/12 23:00:00;0
2016/09/13 00:00:00;0
2016/09/13 01:00:00;0
```

Comment: Do your actual data have more than one day's worth of readings? Why do you replace dates in 2021 with dates in 2022?

Comment: Yes they have more than one day of readings, I was trying to read every hour of the day, and calculate the quantiles for each hour seperately.

Comment: Do you have a link to the full data? I ask because currently you have so little sample data that your quantile spines are invisible.

Comment: I have edited the question in order to include more data, I hope this makes things clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't strictly need Seaborn for what you're doing.

Prefer to express your column names as an immutable tuple.

You should tell `read_csv` to do actual date parsing right off the hop. Your `daterange` method and your `start_date` and `end_date` should not be necessary. As much as possible, use "real" Numpy/Pandas/Matplotlib datetime support, rather than stringy manipulation (`contains`, etc.). There are some annoying gaps that have to be hacked around, but overall this can be dragged into a workable state.

Add PEP484 type hints.

You should not need to hard-code an entire list of percentiles (i.e. `pct0.1`, etc.) and this should be done in a loop. Once properly abstracted, you'll find that you aren't limited to ten quantiles - you could just as easily use 20 or more. This should be explained in your graph with a side colour bar.

Don't `arange/10`; use `linspace` instead.

Don't call `quantile()` once for each of your quantiles; instead call it once passing the entire array for this operation to vectorise.

I don't think it's appropriate to set `xs`, the horizontal axis of your plot, to be an `arange` over the entire dataframe: instead, you should apply grouping over the time.

Avoid calling `plt.*` functions when more direct and explicit `ax.*` and `fig.*` methods are available.

I find the automatic y-limits to fit somewhat better than your hard-coded 3200.

This may sound radical, but you should replace your `Greens` with a perceptually uniform colour map. I've shown a common one - `viridis` - but there are others. If you want to learn more, this is a fairly deep rabbit hole but fascinating reading material. Long story short, such a colour map is a higher-fidelity human-computer interface.

### Suggested

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, date, time

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable, get_cmap
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
from pandas.core.groupby import SeriesGroupBy


def load_data(
    filename: str = 'WTPV_Spring_2016.csv',
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Load the indicated CSV, parsing dates.
    """

    return pd.read_csv(
        filepath_or_buffer=filename,
        names=('Date', 'Energy'), parse_dates=[0],
        encoding='utf8', delimiter=';',
    )


def make_quantiles(
    df: pd.DataFrame,
    quantiles: np.ndarray,
) -> pd.Series:
    """
    Apply the given quantiles over time groups. The input quantiles are assumed
    to include 0 and 1 but these are not included in the calculation.
    The output is a series with a multi-level index: time, quantile. For plot
    compatibility the time is represented as a time of day on Jan 1 1970.
    """
    fake_date = date(1970, 1, 1)
    def dt_to_time(t: time) -> datetime:
        return datetime.combine(fake_date, t)

    times = df.Date.dt.time.apply(dt_to_time)
    df.set_index(times, inplace=True)
    by_time: SeriesGroupBy = df.Energy.groupby(level=0)
    bands = by_time.quantile(quantiles[1:-1])
    bands.index.names = ('Time', 'Quantile')
    return bands


def plot(quantiles: np.ndarray, bands: pd.Series) -> plt.Figure:
    """
    Plot the given quantile bands as filled regions with an associated colour
    bar. The colour bar shows only the first half of the quantile range; the
    second half is symmetric and implied.
    """
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_title('WT & PV Spring 2016')
    ax.set_xlabel('Time')
    ax.set_ylabel('Energy (MWh)')

    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%H:%M'))

    map = ScalarMappable(
        cmap=get_cmap('viridis'),
        norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=0.5),
    )
    ax.set_facecolor(map.to_rgba(0))
    fig.colorbar(map, label='quantile')

    counterposed_quantiles = np.vstack((
        quantiles[1: len(quantiles)//2],
        quantiles[-2: len(quantiles)//2: -1],
    )).T
    for q0, q1 in counterposed_quantiles:
        y0 = bands.loc[:, q0]
        x = y0.index
        y1 = bands.loc[x, q1]
        ax.fill_between(x, y0, y1, color=map.to_rgba(q0))

    q = 0.5
    y = bands.loc[:, q]
    x = y.index
    ax.plot(x, y, color=map.to_rgba(q))

    return fig


def main() -> None:
    quantiles = np.linspace(0, 1, 41)
    data = load_data()
    bands = make_quantiles(data, quantiles)
    plot(quantiles, bands)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: graph]